Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file in Android Studio
Problem
I'm encountering an issue where the Gradle build fails to produce an .apk file. The error message suggests that the file was generated under C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\fimg\build, but the tool couldn't find it.
Error Message
Steps Taken

Checked the build.gradle configuration.
Verified the file path and ensured it is correct.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project using ./gradlew clean and ./gradlew assembleDebug.
Ensured all dependencies are correctly specified.

Environment

Android Studio Version: [Your Android Studio Version]
Gradle Version: [Your Gradle Version]
Operating System: Windows 11

Additional Information
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Where's the error message exactly?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This error occurred when i run my application on my device

I am getting this error while running into emulator
